# AWS - ssh - Permission denied (publickey)

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm getting a

Is it anything to do with this line (it should be a perfectly valid key as I downloaded it from the AWS EC2 dashboard but that `0x0` looks like a `nil` to me):

```
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem (0x0), explicit
```

in the error output:

```
$ ssh -vvv -i ~/Downloads/ec2-key.pem ec2-user@ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com
OpenSSH_7.4p1, LibreSSL 2.5.0
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/config line 17: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug2: resolving "ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com [some-ip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com:22 as 'ec2-user'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:95
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-ripemd160-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5-96-etm@openssh.com,hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:sxwBkVHafdiOEUPngCxKcPMSIkGj2kYUn3c/ztp+xmg
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:95
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:95
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from some-ip
debug1: Host 'ec2-some-ip.compute-1.amazonaws.com' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/known_hosts:95
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem (0x0), explicit
debug2: key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa (0x7f81226005c0), explicit
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:IHnpZJXfjlsOQ16rhasDRe2BdHBFSw1JxTvDqSkOFys
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/snowcrash/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: send_pubkey_test
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Comment: which type of ami used for launching ec2 ? linux or rhel/centos ?

Comment: ami-22ce4934 (Amazon Linux AMI)

Comment: The key is rejected by the server. Check the server if the files have correct permissions. Have a look into the logs, increase log level ...

Comment: Check your .PEM file again.  It is a bad habit to have private key name as "ec2-key.pem". Many people spend hours then only realise they use the wrong private key.   If the instance is not important, recreate it with a new keypair and name the keypair properly.  Or else, you need to do this : https://aws.amazon.com/articles/5213606968661598

Answer (score 0):

you should set permissions for your private key:

```
chmod 400 /Users/snowcrash/Downloads/ec2-key.pem
```

more info: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/AccessingInstancesLinux.html

Comment: @Snowcrash is AWS Security Group configured properly? 22 port should be opened

Comment: Inbound port 22 is open.

Comment: @Snowcrash did you ever connected via ssh to this server before? did you touch ~/.ssh/id_rsa key on this ec2?

Comment: That is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

This failed authentications can be because of disabled authorized_keys file on server. Sometimes also the name is changed or it is disabled with commented line. Configuration is in

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

and example line is:

```
#AuthorizedKeysFile     %h/.ssh/authorized_keys
```